# Two vector processes come out with different values out by a factor of 17

Tags: c++, unit-testing

I am building some subroutines which use vectors and populate them with various processes. One of these processes is a division of two of the other values. However, when I do this in two different subroutines, my unit tests say that they aren't equal. I have been making some stupid mistakes today, so apologies if it is obvious. The unit test below says that:

> Result Message:    Assert failed. Expected:<-1.15741e-05> Actual:<-0.000208333>

I am using the Visual Studio C++ test framework. Playing with the margin variable in `Assert` shows that all values are within 0.0005 of what I expect, but not 0.00005. My code is producing a value 17 times smaller than I was expecting.

What is wrong with my code? Or how else I can test / debug to make it clear?

```
vector< vector<float> > history;
vector<float> values;
vector< vector<float> > graph;

void populateArray(int input, int time) {
    values.push_back(time);
    values.push_back(input);
    if (history.size() > 0) {
        values.push_back(values[0] - history.back()[0]);
        values.push_back(values[1] - history.back()[1]);
        values.push_back(values[3] / values[2]);
    }

    history.push_back(values);
    values.clear();
};

void drawGraph() {
    float m, c, j, x1, x2;
    vector<float> values;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < history.size() - 1) {
        j = i + 1;
        x1 = history[i][0];
        x2 = history[j][0];
        m = history[j][3] / history[j][2];
        c = history[i][1] - m*x2;
        i++;
        values.push_back(x1);
        values.push_back(x2);
        values.push_back(m);
        values.push_back(c);
        graph.push_back(values);
        values.clear();
    }
};
```

And the Unit Test Code:

```
TEST_METHOD(Graph_Equations_Correct) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {
        drawGraph();
        Assert::AreEqual(graph.at(i)[2], history.at(i)[4]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Test `if (history.size() > 0)` (will have 4 elements) before adding elements to the vector

Comment: @DieterLücking my previous test does do this and ensures history is fully populated

Comment: @DieterLücking Also, the fact that the test is returning two values, rather than an out of reach error etc.

Comment: Isn't that just an epsilon problem?  Expected is `-0.000011575`, actual `-0.000208333`.  They are pretty close, especially if the magnitudes of the values leading to that result are >= 1.0 and since you are using `float` which has a precision of 6 to 7 decimal digits.

Comment: Try using the 3 -argument version of AreEqual, where the 3rd argument is the accuracy e.g. AreEqual(graph.at, history.at, 0.0005) - which treats any difference less than 0.0005 as no difference

Comment: @wallyk Well one is 17 times bigger than the other? As both vectors only deal with floats, I don't see why they would be different?

Comment: @KarlM Thanks, yes that makes the tests pass, but as mentioned in my previous comment, not sure why these two seemingly equivalent operations are coming out with different values?

Comment: Within the `while` loop the third value that is pushed into the `values` array is computed by `history[j][3] / history[j][2]` with `j` being equal to `i + 1`, so I would say that, given the provided code, the following assertion should hold in the test: `Assert::AreEqual(graph.at(i)[2], history.at(i+1)[4]);`

Comment: @ChristophFreundl Hmmm, that throws an `Unhandled C++ Exception`

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Well, could be that there is an issue at the end of the loop. I just wanted to point out that the code within `drawGraph()` does not match the assertion in the unit test, so I guess there is a typo in one of the places and I provided the seemingly correct unit test for the provided `drawGraph` implementation. You could alternatively change the statement within `drawGraph` to `m = history[i][3] / history[i][2];` in order to meet the original assertion. However, there is no hint how the loop end `10` in the test is related to the size of `history`.

Comment: @ChristophFreundl Ahh, got it! Thank you for that.